# Animation stops when UIView reappears on scrolling UITableView

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, core-animation

I have an spinning UIView to show progress in each cell of a UITableView and I am using this function to animate UIViews:

```
func rotate360Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0) {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat.pi * 2
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration
    rotateAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    self.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

It works fine when the cells appears first but when you scroll the UITableView and the cells disappear and after that they shows up by scrolling again, their animations are stopped. I tried calling the method for them again after reappearing but it didn't work. what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

`UITableViewCell` objects are reusable and you need to restore the animation in [prepareForReuse:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) or [tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview) method.

```
func getRotate360DegreesAnimation(duration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0) -> CABasicAnimation {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotateAnimation.toValue = .pi * 2
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration
    rotateAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
    return rotateAnimation
}

func restoreAnimation() {
    let animation = getRotate360DegreesAnimation()
    layer.removeAllAnimations()
    layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
}
```